# How to get header response and response body separatey in curlpp response

Tags: c++, c++11, curlpp

I am new to C++ and curlpp, and I needed the header response and the response body from the curlpp response, but what is happening is I am getting both the things in the same string, is there any way or any flag which will help me in storing the header response and response body separately.

```
   std::ostringstream respMsg;

   request.setOpt(new PostFields(body));

   request.setOpt(new PostFieldSize(body.size()));
   request.setOpt(new Header(1));
   request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::WriteStream(&respMsg));

   if (curlpp::infos::ResponseCode::get(request) == 200){
        // success

        std::cout << respMsg.str() << std::endl;

        json data = parse(respMsg.str())

   } else {

      // failure

      std::cout << respMsg.str() << std::endl;

   }
```

What I am expecting is in "if" part, I just need the json string, but I am getting header response + JSON string, which I am not able to separate, is there any setOPt flag or any way to get both the things separately, 
NOTE: I also need the header response in else part to print the error message. Any pointers are appreciated. Thanks in advance and sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The easiest way:

You can simply split the response:

```
std::string response = respMsg.str();
size_t endOfHeader = response.find("\r\n\r\n");

if (endOfHeader != std::string::npos) {
    std::string header = response.substr(0, endOfHeader);
    std::string body = response.substr(endOfHeader + 4);
}
```

### The best way:

If you need only the response body, you can disable the `header` option using 
`request.setOpt(new Header(0));` or simply removing the line.

if you need the headers too, you can disable the `header` and use the `HeaderFunction` option.

```
std::string headers;

size_t HeaderCallback(char* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb)
{
    int totalSize = size * nmemb;
    headers += std::string(ptr, totalSize);
    return totalSize;
}

request.setOpt(curlpp::options::HeaderFunction(HeaderCallback));
```

You can understand better the options if you read the `libcurl` API: [here](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/). (`curlpp`is just a wrapper to `libcurl`).

The `header_function` documentation is [here](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION.html).

Comment: Thanks, this solution is acceptable, but I was expecting that curlpp would be having something like **response.body** which will give me only body and **response.header** which will provide me header.